# does wrk2 benchmark output give more info using lua script

Tags: lua, benchmarking, wrk

i tried asking this on the wrk2 github page but it seems the team is not active on their issues thread.

...
Does the report given at the end of a wrk2 run differ in any way from the report values that could be extracted from a report.lua script?
basically; does using a lua script provide any additional information on the test results than the default/regular output report produced at executing wtk2?